# Раскрыть список / преобразовать список списков (2D) в плоский список (1D)

Tags: python, база-данных, списки

```
lis = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтоб список выше преобразовался в строку/кортеж '1, 2, 3, 4'?

Р.S.
    Такой список я получил из sqlite3, если кому интересно.

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться методом [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain


items = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
items = list(chain(*items))

print(items)                       # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(tuple(items))                # (1, 2, 3, 4)

print(', '.join(map(str, items)))        # "1, 2, 3, 4"
# OR:
print(', '.join(str(i) for i in items))  # "1, 2, 3, 4"
```