# Достать значения из списка списков, используя list comprehension, а не цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Дан список:

```
l1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

нужно преобразовать его в список вида:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Как это сделать с помощью цикла for, я знаю:

```
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    for j in i:
        l2.append(j)
```

Как сделать это с помщью list comprehension?
Решение должно быть в одной строчке, т.е. к примеру:

```
l2 = [*решение с использованием list comprehension*]
```

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу никак допарить как сделать это не циклом, а через list comprehension...

Comment: @MaxU [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837424/420098) не совсем list comprehension, я потому и свой удалил

Comment: @Jack_oS, ok, переоткрыл)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
l2 = [j for i in l1 for j in i]
print(l2)
```

Comment: Вы могли бы пожалуйста пояснить, что происходит в вашем коде?

Comment: списковое включение (list comprehension) в списковом включении там происходит

Answer (score 1):

Bариант c accumulate:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

a = [[1,2], [2,5], [4,4]]
b = [i for i in accumulate(a)][-1]
print(b)

# [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4]
```

или c reduce

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

a = [[1,2], [2,5], [4,4]]
b = [i for i in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, a)]
print(b)

b = [i for i in reduce(operator.add, a)]
print(b)

# [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4]
```

Comment: всё это - list comprehension?

Comment: @Jack_oS, да :)